# Cassandra range scan on columns

Tags: ruby, nosql, cassandra

I am interesting in doing a range scan on columns for a particular row key. So far, using Twitter's cassandra client, it was straight forward to figure out a range scan for int based columns:

```
db.get(:cf, rk, {:start => 1, :finish => 10})
```

I cannot for the life of me however, find documentation on DataStax's site on how to do start/finish scans based on other data types, even for text/utf8.

I ran into a blog post where the poster was using the tilde "~" in order to note the end of an ASCII range scan. Is there an official page on DataStax's website that documents the different range scans one can perform on columns based on their datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra stores all data in a row sorted based on the comparator that you defined for the column family. The most accurate information about the comparator types will be found directly in the source tree. Each type has a corresponding class in the [db/marshal directory](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal). If you look at the [UTF8Type.java](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal/UTF8Type.java) class you can see it implements a compare method that (eventually) does a byte by byte comparison.

So for an ascii encoding you will get an ascii sort where:

```
"A" < "AA" < "a" < "aa"
```